# Disable automatic addition of new files in Visual Studio 2015 for ASP.NET 5 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Is there any way to disable or opt-out of the automatic addition of new files for ASP.NET 5 in Visual Studio 2015?

Our software development shop has a single user checkout policy in place, where developers can only check out files one at a time.  This is causing issues with ASP.NET 5, as any generated files are automatically being added to the project in Visual Studio 2015, which in turn are causing them to be added to TFS.  This causes one developer to block another, as they cannot build and generate the same output files.

For example, Typescript files are being compiled and copied to folders under wwwroot.  The first developer that does this causes Visual Studio 2015 to add those files to the solution, which in turn causes them to be added to TFS.  The next developer then can't build because these files are currently checked out to another developer.

We have been able to temporarily prevent this by cloaking the wwwroot folder in TFS.  However, we would not want to have every developer have to remember to do this.  Plus we have to decloak wwwroot to make code changes to web.config, for example, and then have to re-cloak it afterwards.  And then developers have to decloak to get the latest version of the changes to this file, then re-cloak afterwards.

We would rather explicitly choose to add a file to the project in Visual Studio 2015, so generated files aren't automatically added to the project.

We also cannot change the TFS checkout policy to allow multi-user checkouts.  If we could set a multi-user checkout policy at a folder level in Source Control Explorer in TFS 2010, that might solve some of these problems as well.  But TFS 2010 doesn't allow this.

Comment: Move to git. Seriously.

Comment: "Our software development shop has a single user checkout policy in place, where developers can only check out files one at a time." - really?! It's 2015 and you're not restricted to Visual Source Safe any more! The policy needs changing to keep up to date with modern team development.

Comment: "Our software development shop has a single user checkout policy in place, where developers can only check out files one at a time" It's time people stop being afraid of merging.

Comment: We are looking for a reasonable solution that can be implemented in our current environment.  Changing policy or source control is far beyond what we can do at this time.

Comment: Extremely annoying for bower_components or grunt tasks that build local files in the wwwroot folder. Using .tfignore (with Local workspace) doesn't work on these projects and when I've tried to use cloaking I receive a modal error dialog `Error - {x} error encountered attempting to perform the add operation on x item(s) First error encountered: The item '{filename}' has been cloaked. See output tool window for information on any other errors.`

Comment: That's one level of annoyance that we've run across.  We also hit the maximum path issue in Windows:  (1) when moving, our paths have to be extra-short due to the depth of nesting of the DLLs and folders under the web site.  Any DLLs with long names may be at or over the limit (Microsoft DLL hit this).  (2) when building, node_modules is super-nested, even though we've got NPM 3.5.3 installed.  flatten-packages has to be run twice (not once) to de-nest node_modules during prepublish, or our CI server can't delete the folder due to the depth of nesting of node_modules.  Anyway, just an FYI.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is one of those situations where you're fighting against a tool/process instead of just "going with the flow". Either you need to reform your checkin/checkout process to conform to the new ASP.NET 5 methodologies (including the new xproj format) or you need to stick to older technology that supports your process.